# How to create Multimedia Components in specific Publication using Experience Manager

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

It is possible to create a new multimedia component by Experience Manager,
by using "Drag and drop a file here or click to upload a new file into this folder" menu.

But when I create a multimedia component, it is created in different Publication than what I expected.

My BluePrint structure is as follows.

- 02 Global Content
- 06 Translation
- 07 Country Site

(There are some "Regional" layers between 02 Global Content and 06 Translation, but omitting them to simplify.)

When I use Experience Manager on 07 Country Site, my desired behavior is:

- Components created in "02 Global Content" are localized or edited in the  "06 Translation" Publication
- New multimedia components are created in the "07 Country Site" Publication

So I configured the "BluePrint Context Setting" for Components of the website published from the "07 Country Site" Publication as:

- Alternative BluePrint Publication is "06 Translation".
- Checkbox "Also create Components..." is OFF.

However, the multimedia components are still being created in the "06 Translation" Publication.

(If the "Also create Components..." checkbox is ON, the result was still the same - with the Multimedia Components being created in the '06 Translation' Publication.)

How can I configure this so that new multimedia components are created in the "07 Country Site" Publication?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour that you are seeing is not what I would expect either.

If you un-tick the "Also create components in this publication", then I would expect your multimedia (and all other new Components) to be created in the '07 Country Site' Publication in which you are working.

I have the following suggestions...

1) Have you definitely clicked on the "Apply changes" button after changing the setting?

[image]

2) It may also be worth making sure that the URL for your website is correct in your cd_dynamic_conf.xml configuration file (as this maps the URL to the Publication Id):

```
<Publication Id="XX">
    <Host Domain="your-url" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/de"/>
</Publication>
```

3) ..and that the URL is correct within the 'Session Preview' tab of Publication Target.

[image]

Comment: I think configuration is correct because session preview is working good. But when I create a new component that is NOT MMC, it's created in a publication where proto type is created or localized at.If proto type is in the "02 Global Content", new component is created there, and if proto type is localized at the "07 Country Site", new component is created in the "07 Country Site". Is this correct behavior? If not,there might be miss configuration.